# ¿Abrir aplicación Java en J2ME Loader?

Tags: java

NetBeans IDE 8.2
Quiero ejecutar una aplicación .jar generada por NetBeans. al intentar ejecutarla en J2ME Loader para Android está sólo presenta un texto de error que dice "Broken Manifest". He buscado posibles soluciones sin suerte. El código que tengo es el de desplegar un JFrame. Una vez logrado ésto sería posible continuar el desarrollo.

```
package javaapplication94;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Frame extends JFrame {

    public Frame() {
        setBounds(300, 300, 280, 350);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    private JTextArea areatexto;
}
```

Comment: tengo ya bastante tiempo haciendome la misma pregunta y aun no he logrado encontrar nada...

Comment: ¿Has puesto el jar como executable jar?